# Get the column name of the current row in mutate dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table:

```
df <- data.frame(player_id= c(1, 3),
                 goals= c(22,44))
```

I want to modify all the columns so that each row will contain the name of the column alongside its value. I want a generic solution that can be applied to any number of columns and using the dplyr package.

The resulting table here should look like this:

| player_id | goals |
| --- | --- |
| player_id_1 | goals_22 |
| player_id_3 | goals_44 |

My initial try is like this:

```
df%>%
mutate(across(everything(),~ paste0({.col},'_',{.row})))
```

With what should I replace .col  and .row to get for each row the name of the column pasted to the value of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
df%>%mutate(across(everything(),~ paste0(cur_column(),'_',.)))
```

`cur_column()` gives the name of the current column. The '.' is the value of the current row being processed. `paste0()` concatenate the two, with '_' in between.